# I am trying to center align the menu

Tags: css, center, centering

I am a newbie in CSS. I am learning by playing with the code of a WordPress theme.
Last time I posted this issue but I contracted covid and was hospitalized for more than two weeks. I have deleted the old question and broken the initial question into two parts. This is the first part.
[image]

To remove the Site-Name on the left side.  I used display: none.

```
<div id="header-left">
    
    <div id="hgroup" class="logo-disable">
        <h1 id="site-title">
            <a href="https://wp-themes.com/catch-kathmandu/" title="Catch Kathmandu" rel="home">Catch Kathmandu</a>
        </h1>
        <h2 id="site-description"> Catch Kathmandu Theme is a fully responsive WordPress theme that looks elegant on any devices.</h2>
    </div><!-- #hgroup -->
</div>


#header-left {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
color: #404040;
line-height: 1.8;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
word-wrap: break-word;
border: 0;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
float: left;
max-width: 100%;
display: none;
}
```

To center-align the menu on the right side.

```
<div id="header-right" class="header-sidebar widget-area">
                    <aside class="widget widget_nav_menu">
                        <div id="primary-menu-wrapper" class="menu-wrapper">
        <div class="menu-toggle-wrapper">
            <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="main-menu" aria-expanded="false"><span class="menu-label">Menu</span></button>
        </div><!-- .menu-toggle-wrapper -->

        <div class="menu-inside-wrapper">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Primary Menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <ul id="menu-primary-items" class="menu nav-menu"><li class="current-menu-item"><a href="https://wp-themes.com/catch-kathmandu/">Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="https://wp-themes.com/catch-kathmandu/?page_id=2">About</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-182"><a href="https://wp-themes.com/catch-kathmandu/?page_id=182">Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-46 page_item_has_children" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="https://wp-themes.com/catch-kathmandu/?page_id=46">Parent Page</a><button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"><span class="screen-reader-text">expand child menu</span></button><ul class="children"><li class="page_item page-item-49"><a href="https://wp-themes.com/catch-kathmandu/?page_id=49">Sub-page</a></li></ul></li></ul>                </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
        </div>


#header-right {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
color: #404040;
line-height: 1.8;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
word-wrap: break-word;
border: 0;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
padding-top: 50px;
float: right;
margin-right: 33%;
}
```

I reached my center alignment by reducing the margin-right from 50% then to 33%. Though the sweet spot is between 32% to 33%.

I also tried center-align the menu with pixels(margin-right :400px).

The difference between both methods is visible when I reduce the screen size. 33% mostly remains center-align but the px changes the position of the menu, as the screen changes.

Is there any other way I could center the menu?

Comment: Please post the combination of HTML and CSS together.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML to let us try to see what's wrong? Please also consider putting the HTML and CSS in Snippet in your question.

Comment: Flexbox or Grid?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question** [ask]

Comment: @Nitheesh I have updated the question with the required HTML and CSS. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @DhanaD. I have updated the question with the required HTML and CSS. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I am trying to learn center-aligning without flex or grid right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to center items depending on their block type.

You can use ***display flex*** on the *parent* and then add a `justify-content: center` to center the children items on the page horizontally, see [***flex axis*** - in basic concepts of flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#the_two_axes_of_flexbox) for more info.

Then you can use ***flex*** property on the children and can add a number to that property to tell CSS how much of the parents width that child will take up.

For example if I set both to child elements to `flex: 1` they will take up ***50%***, if there were three child elements all with a `flex: 1`, they would then take up 33% of their parents width. I can also place a *percentage* on the ***flex*** property as well => `.header` set `flex: 60%` and `.nav-parent` set `flex: 40%`, they will then take up their set percentages of the parents width.

Furthermore I can add `display: flex` properties to the *child elements* as well to further center their contents, as I have done on the `.menu` class which is a child of the `.nav-parent`. These can then be further align and centered using the axis centering properties for flex, `justify-content` and `align-items`. The good thing is that these properties are dynamic in that they scale to fit browser sizes as well.

```css
.nav-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.header h1 {  
  line-height: 1px;
}

.header {  
  flex: 60%;
}

.nav-parent {
  flex: 40%;
}

.header span {
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li ~ li {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.btn {
  flex: 1;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #555;
  font-size: .8rem; 
}

.active {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-section">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Catch Kathmandu</h1>
    <span>Catch Kathmandu Theme is a fully responsive WordPress theme that looks elegant on any device.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-parent">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="home active btn">Home</li>
      <li class="about btn">About</li>
      <li class="contact btn">Contact</li>
      <li class="parent btn">Page</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have just started learning flex. Right now I am trying to center-align without flex. Now I will apply your solution to my problem and learn a new method. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way I could center the menu?

There are a good handful of ways you can center the menu.

If your menu is a block-level element with an explicitly declared `width`, one of the most basic techniques is applying the keyword `auto` to `margin-right` and `margin-left`:

```
.my-menu {
  margin-top: 12px;     // <= Just an example, you can use any value
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;  // <= Just an example, you can use any value
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

the *CSS shorthand* for these four declarations is:

```
.my-menu {
  margin: 12px auto 12px auto;
}
```

or, since the vertical and horizontal values are the same, you can declare:

```
.my-menu {
  margin: 12px auto;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.my-menu {
 display: block;
 margin: 12px auto;
}

.my-menu.vertical {
   width: 100px;
}

.my-menu.horizontal {
   width: 396px;
   padding: 0;
}

.my-menu.horizontal li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.my-menu.horizontal li::before {
  content: '•';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-menu vertical">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="my-menu horizontal">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was trying with auto and margin but was not successful. Your answer gave me new insight. Thank you for the help.